# Non-linear regression. Need some help implementing a model from a paper

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, starting-values

I found this [paper](https://academic.oup.com/njaf/article/18/3/87/4788527?login=false) very useful for my research, however, I'm not familiar with non-linear regressions and I'm finding it tricky replicating it.

Using the first f=model for example:

```
HT = 1.3 + a(1-e^-b*DBH)^c
```

This is what I have through the help of someone

```
cr.fit = nls(y~a*(1-exp(-b*x))^c,start=list(a=a,b=b,c=c))
summary(cr.fit)
```

Now when trying to predict I'm doing this:

```
TH <- 1.3+(a*(1-exp(-b*10.9))^c)
```

So far, I have been testing the predictions and sometimes it produces spot-on results, other times it doesn't. I believe this has to do with the starting values I'm using. I'm fairly new to this statistical tool as well as also new to forestry research so I neither have technical knowledge nor domain knowledge for this. My question is what is a good empirical way to get starting values for this type of analysis?

With my personal research on this, I understand this may be difficult to answer but if you were in my shoes, how would you go about this?

I'm just building a methodology for my research so I'm just exploring this to see if it works for me, if I get good results, I would of course seek further knowledge on this to be able to determine good starting values for the species and location I'm researching on.

I have sample data for this [here](https://github.com/brian-o-mars/height-diameter-sim). The relevant columns are HT and DIA.

Comment: There's potentially more structure in your data than just the height and diameter-at-breast-height (DBH). [`tree_data.csv`](https://github.com/brian-o-mars/height-diameter-sim/blob/main/tree_data.csv) shows additional variables about where and when the data collection took place which might be explanatory. I would also develop a [non-linear mixed effects model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_mixed-effects_model) for comparison.

Comment: @Galen Thanks a lot for your comment. You're correct. In fact, the larger dataset contains even more variables that may provide better statistical results. I'm however just trying to validate this methodology first before utilizing it. Most papers I've read on this actually just used Height and diameter but they created models for future predictions. I, on the other hand, need a model for backward predictions rather so I'm not fully confident just using this methodology without first testing it out. I just need to figure out how to really implement this lol.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brian-o-mars/height-diameter-sim/main/tree_data.csv")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DT, aes(DIA, HT)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Clearly, the variance increases with increasing HT values. This means a log-transformation is a good idea.

The log-transformed model:

$log(y) = log(a) + c \cdot log(1 - exp(-b \cdot x))$

Luckily, this model is linear in `log(a)` and `c`, which means we only need a starting parameter for `b`. Often you can derive that from domain knowledge (e.g., check some publications). I will just guess it.

```
DT[, y := HT - 1.3]
DT[, logy := log(y)]

fitlog <- nls(logy ~ cbind(1, log(1 - exp(-b*DIA))), data = DT, 
              start = list(b = 0.1), algorithm = "plinear")
summary(fitlog)
#Formula: logy ~ cbind(1, log(1 - exp(-b * DIA)))
#
#Parameters:
#      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#b      0.14147    0.00790   17.91   <2e-16 ***
#.lin1  4.46843    0.02337  191.24   <2e-16 ***
#.lin2  1.20448    0.03098   38.88   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 0.1988 on 1951 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.797e-06
```

A diagnostic plot shows that we have pretty good homogeneity:

```
plot(residuals(fitlog) ~ fitted(fitlog))
abline(0, 0)
```

[image: diagnostic plot]
(You should investigate that one extreme value.)

Let's look at predictions. On the log-scale:

```
ggplot(DT, aes(DIA, logy)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun = \(x) predict(fitlog, newdata = data.frame(DIA = x)),
                color = "red")
```

[image: plot of data and predictions on log-scale]

And on the original scale:

```
ggplot(DT, aes(DIA, HT)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun = \(x) exp(predict(fitlog, newdata = data.frame(DIA = x))) + 1.3,
                color = "red")
```

[image: data and predictions on original scale]

Now, obviously, for large diameters you will have pretty large differences between measured and predicted values as you can see in the plot. If you want to improve predictions you need to include the additional data in your fits. Since you appear to have repeated measures, you should do that in any case. This means, you need to fit a non-linear mixed-effects model (see R package `nlme`). Since I don't have a full understanding of your dataset, non-linear mixed-effects models are not trivial to fit, and I have already invested enough time, I'll stop here.